# Tensorflow - How to Convert int32 to string (using Python API for Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Simple question really but cannot seem to find a function in the TensorFlow docs or by googling.

How can I convert a tensor of type `tf.int32` to one of type `tf.string`?

I tried simply casting it with something like this:

```
x = tf.constant([1,2,3], dtype=tf.int32)
x_as_string = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.string) # hoping for this output: [ '1', '2', '3' ]

with tf.Session() as sess:
  res = sess.run(x_as_string)
```

but hit the error message:

> Cast int32 to string is not supported

Is there a simple function somewhere in the documentation that I am missing?

---

UPDATE:

To clarify: I realise I could 'work around' this issue using a python function with `tf.py_func` but asking if there is a solution in TensorFlow itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the newly added (v1.12.0) [`tf.strings.format`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/format):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32)
x_as_string = tf.map_fn(lambda xi: tf.strings.format('{}', xi), x, dtype=tf.string)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  res = sess.run(x_as_string)
  print(res)
  # [b'1' b'2' b'3']
```

For Tensorflow v2,

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32)
x_as_string = tf.map_fn(lambda xi: tf.strings.format('{}', xi), x, dtype=tf.string)

print(x_as_string.numpy())
# [b'1' b'2' b'3']
```

Answer (score 5):

tf.as_string()
Converts each entry in the given tensor to strings.  Supports many numeric