# tensorflow cast tf.int32 to tf.string in version suitable for Google cloud ml-engine

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I would like to convert a tensor of type `tf.int32` to one of type `tf.string`.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53305286/2455494) I know that in version 1.12 I can use `tf.strings.format`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32)
x_as_string = tf.map_fn(lambda xi: tf.strings.format('{}', xi), x, dtype=tf.string)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  res = sess.run(x_as_string)
  print(res)
  # [b'1' b'2' b'3']
```

But i would like to do this operation on Google cloud ml-engine which (today) only supports up to version 1.10.

Is there an alternative operation I can use in an earlier version of tensorflow?

Or, alternatively, is there anyway to use the new version of TensorFlow in Google cloud ml-engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.as_string`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/as_string) should work to convert ints to strings.